# Comparing shoreline pixels across Sentinel data with Google Earth Engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, raster-calculator, change-detection

I am trying to determine the change/reduction of shorelines using Sentinel 2 data. I thought it would require heavy processing power and was thus leaning towards using Google Earth Engine for the analysis.  However, I don't have a lot of experience in raster analysis or GEE... how would one approach this?  I'd like to:

1. Select/filter pixels to only the shoreline.
2. Determine which pixels should be counted as "shore"/"land".
3. Apply the analysis to images from six-month intervals to determine change over time.

[image]

Comment: you tapped into a whole research area with a bunch of options, pitfalls and limitations. Basically you want to automatically separate land and water (canny edge detection + otsu thresholding) and automatically assess changes over time. I'd say your best starting point for that is coastsat toolbox: https://github.com/kvos/CoastSat but that would require you setting up the Python GEE API...

Comment: Depending on where you're looking, you are probably unlikely to see much coastline change using 10m sentinel-2 pixels over just the 5 years that S2 has been flying.